# How to reverse engineer db with original table names and properties using ef core

Tags: entity-framework-core, reverse-engineering

I'm using scaffold dbcontext to reverse engineer an existing database in ef core

```
Scaffold-DbContext "User Id=x;Password=x;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxxx)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = xx)))" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -Context KoopNextContext -Tables EXCHANGE_RATES_D, EXCHANGE_RATES_M
```

but the table names and property names are pascalcased..

my EXCHANGE_RATES_D table becomes ExchangeRatesD where as ERD_ROWID property becomes ErdRowid

is there a way I can fix this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

apparently I was missing -UseDatabaseNames